# Xcode duplicated device destination in scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I using Xcode 5.0.2
Xcode show duplicate device name in destination after connect my iPhone

[image: xcode]

I try to build each destination, result is totally different.

Have someone can teach me how to delete an destination, just keep one!

(I have try to clean & deleted derived data and restart, but not work!)

Comment: And are there two devices in the *Devices* tab in the *Xcode Organizer* window?

Comment: I removed all devices in Organizer and reconnect iPhone, Xcode still show two destination in scheme.

Comment: I find the answer, just leave iPhoneOS7.0.sdk in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs, delete others.